# Custom estimator for GridSearchCV in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to implement a custom estimator and optimise four parameters using `GridSearchCV`. I haven't fully understood this yet and am having some problems (see **update** below).

Here is my estimator with `coeffs` containing the four parameters I want to optimise. `v1, v2, sm` are the input data (NumPy arrays).

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
import numpy as np

class wc(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
        def __init__(self, verbose=False):
            self.verbose = verbose
    
        def fit(self, coeffs, v1, v2, sm):
            return self
    
        def predict(self, coeffs, v1, v2, sm):
    
            a = coeffs[0]
            b = coeffs[1]
            c = coeffs[2]
            d = coeffs[3]
    
            theta = 40.0
            t = np.exp(-2 * b * v2 * np.arccos(np.cos(theta * np.pi / 180)))
            sigmav = a * v1 * np.cos(theta) * (1 - t ** 2)
    
            sigmas = c + d * sm
            sigma = sigmav + t ** 2 * sigmas
            return sigma
    
    
wcm = wc()
```

Now I define a function to do the grid search:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

def wcm_params_selection(v1, v2, sm, y, nfolds):

    a = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
    b = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
    c = np.arange(-10.0, 0, 0.1)
    d = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)

    param_grid = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}
    my_func = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(wcm, param_grid, scoring=my_func, cv=nfolds)
    grid_search.fit(v1=v1, v2=v2, sm=sm, y=y)
    return grid_search.best_params_
```

Running

```py
v1,v2,sm = np.array([5.0]),np.array([5.0]),np.array([0.5])  # single predictor test values
y = np.array([-10])  # measurement

wcm_params_selection(v1=v1, v2=v2, sm=sm, y=y, nfolds=5)
```

This gives me the error message `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'`.

**update:**
I have updated my code quite a bit and I think I'm getting closer. It would be great to get some feedback on the correctness of this. With some test data, I seem to end up with `a` and `b` always being 0.

The estimator class:

```py
class wc(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def fit(self, X, y):
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        self.is_fitted_ = True
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        X = check_array(X)
        check_is_fitted(self, 'is_fitted_')

        v1 = X[:, 0]
        v2 = X[:, 0]
        sm = X[:, 1]

        theta = 40.0
        t = np.exp(-2 * self.b * v2 * np.arccos(np.cos(theta * np.pi / 180)))
        sigmav = self.a * v1 * np.cos(theta) * (1 - np.power(t, 2))

        sigmas = self.c + self.d * sm
        sigma = sigmav + np.power(t, 2) * sigmas
        return sigma
```

The grid search function:

```py
def wcm_params_selection(X, y, nfolds):
    a = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 1)
    b = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 1)
    c = np.arange(-35, 0, 2)
    d = np.arange(15, 60, 1)

    param_grid = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}
    my_func = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(wc, param_grid, scoring=my_func, cv=2)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search.best_params_
```

and tuning the model to predict values:

```py
wcm_params = wcm_params_selection(X, y, 5)
wcmfit = wc(a=wcm_params['a'], b=wcm_params['b'], c=wcm_params['c'], d=wcm_params['d'])
wcmfit = wcmfit.fit(X, y)
out = wcmfit.predict(X)
score = wcmfit.score(X, y)
```

Unfortunately, I'm totally lost and I always receive 0 for both a and b which can't be correct. Any support would be really appreciated.